# Why is the library I injected into my background script missing it's prototype methods?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting a custom library into my background script in my chrome extension. There are methods on the prototype of the object but when I test my extension it says the method I am calling is undefined. I pop open the debugger to find that all of my libraries prototype methods are missing. Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Travelers Learning",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Chrome extension to enable xAPI",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["tx.js", "main.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": [ "ramda.js", "tincan.js", "interactionProfile.js", "tx.js", "all.js"]
    },
    {
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["interactionProfile.js", "tx.js", "youtube.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "main.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

```
//all.js

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({contentScriptQuery: ''}, (tx) => {


// This callback catches a newly created instance of my tx library, it has some variables on it but the prototype methods are missing. The prototype methods are missing from any sub objects too.

    tx.registerProfile('launched', interactionProfile);
    tx.sendStatement('launched', {
        verbLabel: 'experienced',
        userEmail: tx.getUserId(),
        UUID: tx.getUUID(),
        objectID: 'Page Title',
        objectDisplayName: 'Page Title',
        iriRoot: 'http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/'
    });

});
```

```
//main.js

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tabInfo){
    chrome.tabs.get(tabInfo.tabId, function(tab) {
        console.log(tab);
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    (request, sender, sendResponse) => {
        tx.TX.create({
            endpoint: '*****',
            username: '*****',
            password: '*****',
            allowfail: false,
            env: "sandbox",
            xapiEndpoint: '*****'
        })
            .then((tx) => {
                // Prototype methods are still present here.
                return sendResponse(tx)
            });
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Ah I see it must be serializing the object when I pass it and removing the methods that way. Is there any way to avoid the serialization step?

Comment: No, the messages are always serialized.